# httpbuilder-ng no signature of method multipart() when attempting a post

Tags: post, groovy, multipart, httpbuilder-ng

I implemented this code almost exactly as listed in the examples for HttpBuilder-NG and it is not working for me. For some reason it does not recognize the multipart as a method. Example from the creators of the libraries https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5/#_multipart

```
def uploadFileNG(String targetTestId, String filePath) {
    File someFile = new File(filePath)
    OkHttpBuilder.configure {
        request.uri = blazeUrl
    }.post {
        request.uri.path = "/api/latest/tests/${targetTestId}/files"
        request.contentType = "multipart/form-data"
        request.body = multipart {
            field 'name', 'This is my file'
            part 'file', someFile.getName(), 'text/plain', someFile
        }
        request.encoder 'multipart/form-data', OkHttpEncoders.&multipart
    }
}
```

Comment: The full error message?

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.foulk.utils.blazeapi.BlazeApiHelper.multipart() is applicable for argument types: (com.foulk.utils.blazeapi.BlazeApiHelper$_uploadFileNG_closure9$_closure12) values: [com.foulk.utils.blazeapi.BlazeApiHelper$_uploadFileNG_closure9$_closure12@704deff2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multipart` method (in `request.body` config) needs to be statically imported (I will update the docs to be more explicit about this).

This would be `import static groovyx.net.http.MultipartContent.multipart` for your example.

Comment: I thought I had tried that before but apparently I did not. The static import of multipart worked perfectly, thank you for the guidance.

Comment: I just pushed the doc update as well so others will not fall into the same trap. :-)